# Multivariate regression with glm: logical subscript too long

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I am teaching myself multivariate regression and I am trying to simulate a multivariate random variable and construct a generalized linear model to fit it. 
Here is my code:

```
#Clear Previous
rm(list=ls())


cmp = 2     #Number of components in sample 
n = 10      #Number of simulated data points 

B = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2,byrow=TRUE) #Coefficient matrix 

#Simulate model

X = matrix(rep(0,2*n), nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)          #Initiate independent matrix 
Y = matrix(rep(0,2*n), nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)          #Initiate response matrix

for (j in 1:cmp){

  X[j,] = rnorm(n)      #independent data 
  e = rnorm(n)          #error term
  Y[j,] = B[j,1]+ B[j,2]*X[j,] + e
}

#Linear Regression 

fit = glm(Y~X,family = gaussian())
fit
```

This produces the following error in the function glm:

```
Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

I am quite unsure what the problem is.

Comment: Do you intentionally have two rows and ten columns in your matrices? Do you want to do the regression by rows or columns perhaps?

Comment: @nya It was intentional yes. I have tried to make it column vectors instead, that is both X and Y are 10x2 matrices, and the problem persists.

Comment: You need vectors for both `X` and `Y` to run `glm`: "A typical predictor has the form response ~ terms where response is the (numeric) response vector and terms is a series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for response."

Comment: @nya I see. But I am not sure I understand. If I am intending to regress a response vector Y = (y1, y2) from a predictor vector X = (x1,x2), and I have say 10 measurements, then the "data" would be a 10x2 matrix of responses and 10x2 in independents. So if glm only takes vector inputs, how could I incorporate all of the data for both variables? Or do I have to do it component wise? For instance this:

Z = c(Y[,1],Y[,2])
W = c(X[,1],X[,2])
fit = glm(Z~W,family = gaussian())

works, but I am unsure on how I could interpret the results.

Comment: Okay so it turns out that I should have been using the function lm instead. Not only can it accept matrix inputs, it also outputs a coefficient matrix instead of a vector. I thought that this is what the generalized linear model was supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

#### Multivariate GLM

GLM is *not* working with multiple dependent variables. You can relate a single column like the code below but you can not do both. It is the independent data that can be multivariate.

Use `Y[1,]` instead of `Y`

```
fit = glm(Y[1,]~t(X),family = gaussian())
```

In addition, the above line uses the transpose `t(X)` instead of `X` because the function GLM will interpret the rows as different measurements.

#### MANOVA/MANCOVA / linear discriminant analysis

in your case, you seem to be using Gaussian distributed errors. For this particular case, there is a method that handles multiple dependent variables. It is MANOVA (if the independent variable is a factor) or MANCOVA (if the independent variable is continuous). You can model it in R as `fit = manova(t(Y)~t(X))`